# How to call a page in another page in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created a page named **footer**, so I have footer/footer.html, footer.ts, footer.scss.

Now I want to call this in the end in all other pages. How can I do that?

Below is my `footer.ts`, I want it to be included in home.html:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-footer',
  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
})
```

Below is my `home.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" item-end>
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
    You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title}}</b>
  </div>

  {{serverstatus}}

  <button (click)="abc()">hii</button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: why don't you add `<page-footer> </page-footer>` at the end of your ion-content ?

Comment: worked, please write answer so i can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `<page-footer> </page-footer` at the end of your ion-content.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" item-end>
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
    You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title}}</b>
  </div>

  {{serverstatus}}

  <button (click)="abc()">hii</button>


  <page-footer> </page-footer>
</ion-content>
<!-- ore here -->
<page-footer> </page-footer>
```

Comment: how to pass navigation params to the footer.ts ??

Comment: via input, like this,
`
<page-footer [navParams]="navparams""></page-footer>
`

Answer (score 0):

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" item-end>
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
    You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title}}</b>
  </div>

  {{serverstatus}}

  <button (click)="abc()">hii</button>

</ion-content>
<page-footer> </page-footer>
```

in home template file you can add the selector of your footer component.

Comment: How would OP go about adding the selector?

Comment: What is OP? @Chris

Comment: The original poster of the question