# call a selector in another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have created a page named header in ionic 3

Now I want to call this at top of other pages like in the home page.

Below is my header.ts, I want it to be included in home.html

**header.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-header',
  templateUrl: 'header.html',
})
export class HeaderPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HeaderPage');
  }

}
```

// app.module.ts

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { HeaderPage } from '../pages/header/header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    HeaderPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    HeaderPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.html

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

 <page-header>loading...</page-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
</ion-content>
```

I am getting below error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'page-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'page-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'page-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I have also seen this stack overflow question: [How do i call a page in another page - IONIC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986822/how-do-i-call-a-page-in-another-page-ionic-2)
 but did not work for me
***Please advise, how can I do that ?***

Comment: what is the issue? are you getting errors?

Comment: i am not getting any error but my  <page-header> content is not displaying inside home

Comment: what is in the page-header.html?

Comment: i have just added hello in my header.html file <ion-content padding>
hello
</ion-content>

Comment: you cant have 2 ion-content tags in a page

Comment: i have change my header,html file as you told <div>
hellow
</div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164956/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: i have replace <ion-content padding> hello </ion-content> with <div> hello </div> as you told me "you cant have 2 ion-content tags in a page"

Comment: does it show if you dont have `ion-header`?

Comment: its work please add as a answer so that i accept it

Comment: actually no.. it wont work.. you will have issues..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889380/including-the-common-header-bar-for-ionic-2-angular-2 this should solve your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [including the common header bar for ionic 2/angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889380/including-the-common-header-bar-for-ionic-2-angular-2)

Comment: i am getting this error :Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'header-page' is not a known element:
1. If 'header-page' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'header-page' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Answer (score 1):

Your `header.html:`

```
<div text-center padding>Loading...</div>
```

header.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HeaderPage } from './header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HeaderPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderPage
  ],
})
export class HeaderPageModule {}
```

home.ts

```
<ion-header>


<ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <page-header></page-header>
  <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will show you the way.
  </p>

  <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
</ion-content>
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({


declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HeaderPageModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: i did HeaderPage to export array also but i am getting below error :i am getting this error :Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'header-page' is not a known element: 1. If 'header-page' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'header-page' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: remove `@IonicPage` from `header.ts` if you have created `header.module.ts` then remove `HeaderPage` from its declaration as well or delete `header.module.ts`, a good idea will be implementing `component `level module and then import modules in `app.module.ts`

Comment: how to import comon-header component in app.module.ts so that it will present at all pages

Comment: not working!,  can you put any example for "implementing component level module and then import modules in app.module.ts"

Comment: I have already done it above, `HeaderPageModule` contain HeaderPage and I have imported that module in `app.module.ts`, its working perfectly with me, you may be missing something, can you please share error message.

Comment: i am getting this error on using your code: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'page-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'page-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'page-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.